# IntelliJ idea Python3 code index error

Tags: python, intellij-idea

There are common.py, environment.py and evaluation.py in the same directory and the Python version is 3.6 but in IntelliJ idea with Python plugin, Unresolved reference error is raised as you can see in the following picture 1.

[image: picture 1]

And after changing `common` to `.common`, there is no error as you see in the following picture.

[image: picture 2]

But the code cannot be run under Python 3.6, how can I change IntelliJ idea settings so that files can be indexed under the same folder and no errors will be reported in picture 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the directory containing `common.py` is marked as a source root in the project structure dialog.